# add WHERE condition to a 3 table LEFT JOIN query...?

Tags: php, mysql, search, where-clause

I'm working my way through the php world but still finding my feet. I've written a query that works nicely for collecting what i need from mysql, but I just cannot get it to work with a `WHERE` condition. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here's my working query without the `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT foo.*, users.name, SUM(bar.amt) Total FROM foo 
     LEFT JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.foo_id 
     LEFT JOIN users ON foo.foo_owner_id = users.id 
     LIMIT 16 GROUP BY foo.id"
```

And here's what I think should work to add the `WHERE` condition but doesn't work...

```
SELECT foo.*, users.name, SUM(bar.amt) Total FROM foo 
     WHERE foo.category = $var LEFT JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.foo_id 
     LEFT JOIN users ON foo.foo_owner_id = users.id LIMIT 16 GROUP BY foo.id"
```

Any and all suggestions are welcome, thanks!!

Comment: Condition should be at end of the statement after `join` . Check this reference -> http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php

Comment: ever had an idea of splitting long lines to let a reader ability to see your query? just curious.

Answer (score 3):

Quite simple: all the `WHERE` conditions should be placed after all the `JOIN`'s.

Comment: thanks for your quick response! I've tried placing it just before the LIMIT condition, as well as between the LIMIT and the GROUP BY, and also at the very end of the query and still no luck..

Comment: Wait no, you were correct. as was Yahia, I just mistyped when i tested it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `WHERE` clause after all the joined tables.  Hence

```
SELECT foo.*, users.name, SUM(bar.amt) Total
FROM foo
    LEFT JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.foo_id
    LEFT JOIN users ON foo.foo_owner_id = users.id
WHERE foo.category = $var
GROUP BY foo.id
LIMIT 16;
```

You probably also want the `LIMIT` clause to be last.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
SELECT 
foo.*, 
users.name, 
SUM(bar.amt) Total 
FROM foo 
LEFT JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.foo_id 
LEFT JOIN users ON foo.foo_owner_id = users.id 
WHERE foo.category = $var 
GROUP BY foo.id
LIMIT 16
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are using left or right join then always use where clause after joins.

```
SELECT foo.*, users.name, SUM(bar.amt) Total
   FROM foo
   LEFT JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.foo_id
   LEFT JOIN users ON foo.foo_owner_id = users.id
   WHERE foo.category = $var
   GROUP BY foo.id
   LIMIT 16;
```

even if u want order by id etc use it before LIMIT